# How to assign parameter's type of generic callback in swift?

Tags: swift, generics, callback

Suppose I have following function:

```
func fetch<T: Codable>(completion: @escaping (_ response: SimpleResult<[T]>) -> Void) {
      completion(parse(result))
}
```

Xcode does not show any error on above function. But how to use it? If I write following, it shows error:

```
fetch { result in 
}
```

It says that "Generic parameter T could not be inferred". I suppose that I should indicate type here. But where should I write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly state the result type:

```
fetch { (result: SimpleResult<YOUR_CODABLE_TYPE>) in
}
```

Comment: FYI that's called type annotation :)